# Rendering a composite: different behavior of a script on command line and in UI

Tags: scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, command-line

A baffling (to me at least) Blender behavior. Here is a pared down version of my compositing setup (A).

[image: A) snapshot of compositing editor: shadow of a sphere from one layer is mixed with cube from another layer, using Alpha Over node. B) Output from the command line: cube only. C) Output from GUI cube + alpha mixed shadow.]

In Compositor, shadow of a sphere from one layer is combined in Alpha Over with cube from another, and piped into a file. The whole thing is scripted. Running the code from the command line (in Blender's batch mode) gives me an image of a cube, without the shadow (B).

If, however, I read the script into Blender GUI, run the script, and then re-render with <kbd>F12</kbd> (Info Editor, Render -> Render Image), I get both the cube and the mixed in shadow (C), which is what I am trying to get. Edit: for this last to work, a Node Editor has to be open, and in compositing mode.

According to the mouseover description, <kbd>F12</kbd>, should be the same as the last line in the script:

`bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True)`

I suspect that GUI is adding something to the setup but I have not been able to figure out what. Any suggestion welcome.

I am using Blender 2.75 and  here is the code, if it helps any:

```
#!bpy
"""
"""

import bpy
from math import radians
import fnmatch
import os


###################################
def delete_old_stuff():

    # escape edit mode
    if bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll():
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    # delete all mesh objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    # delete all lamps
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='LAMP')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

#####################################################################
def set_camera(scene):
    # Set camera rotation in euler angles
    scene.camera.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
    scene.camera.rotation_euler[0] = radians(20)
    scene.camera.rotation_euler[1] = radians(3)
    scene.camera.rotation_euler[2] = 0.0

    # Set camera translation
    scene.camera.location.x =  0.34
    scene.camera.location.y = -1.2
    scene.camera.location.z =  6.7

#####################################################################
def set_lights(scene):
    # ambient
    scene.world.light_settings.use_ambient_occlusion = True
    scene.world.light_settings.distance = 2
    # spotlight - sun
    bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='SUN', location=(-2.0, 0.32, 6.5), rotation=(radians(-21), radians(-5), radians(69)))
    lamp = bpy.context.object
    lamp.data.node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs['Strength'].default_value= 5.0
    lamp.data.node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs['Color'].default_value= (0.43, 0.78,1.0,1.0)
    lamp.cycles_visibility.shadow = False

#####################################################################
def create_objects():
    # it looks like the thing uses the last layer definition seen, not the default one
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), layers=[l==0 for l in range(20)])
    cube = bpy.context.object
    cube.name = "cube"
    cube.data.materials.append (bpy.data.materials.new('Plain Diffuse'))
    cube.active_material.diffuse_color = (0.0665019, 0.0302079, 0.8)

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(0.0, 3.0, 0.0), layers=[l==0 for l in range(20)])
    sphere = bpy.context.object
    sphere.name = "sphere"
    sphere.data.materials.append (bpy.data.materials.new('Plain Diffuse'))
    sphere.active_material.diffuse_color = (0.8, 0.0344425, 0.0344425)


    return [cube, sphere]

#####################################################################
def compositing(scene, outdir, outfile_base_name):

    # let's try to work in some layers
    render_layers = scene.render.layers
    render_layers.active.name = "main"
    render_layers.new("sphere")
    render_layers["main"].layers   = [l==0 for l in range(20)]
    render_layers["sphere"].layers = [l==1 for l in range(20)]
    render_layers["sphere"].use_pass_shadow = True

    scene.layers[0] = True
    scene.layers[1] = True

    # switch on nodes and get tree reference
    scene.use_nodes = True
    tree = scene.node_tree

    # the default nodes are Composite and RenderLayers, that contains our main layer already
    # --> remove them if I am going to run this script repeatedly
    for node in tree.nodes:
         tree.nodes.remove(node)

    links = tree.links

    main_layer_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')
    main_layer_node.layer    = "main"
    main_layer_node.location =  0, -200

    sphere_layer_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')
    sphere_layer_node.layer = "sphere"
    sphere_layer_node.location = -400, 200

    alpha_over_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeAlphaOver')
    alpha_over_node.location = 200, 0
    links.new(main_layer_node.outputs['Image'], alpha_over_node.inputs[2])
    links.new(sphere_layer_node.outputs['Shadow'], alpha_over_node.inputs[1])

    # create output node
    out_node = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeOutputFile')
    out_node.base_path = outdir
    out_node.file_slots[0].path = outfile_base_name
    out_node.location = 400,0
    links.new(alpha_over_node.outputs['Image'], out_node.inputs[0])


###################################
if __name__ == '__main__':

    delete_old_stuff()
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.render.engine="CYCLES"

    set_camera(scene)
    set_lights(scene)

    [cube, sphere] = create_objects()

    #move the sphere to the second layer (index==1)
    sphere.layers = [l==1 for l in range(20)]

    # do some compositing in which we bring the two layers together again:
    compositing(scene, os.getcwd(), "test")

    # rendering
    scene.render.resolution_y = 1024
    scene.render.resolution_x =  512
    scene.cycles.film_transparent = True

    # not working:
    bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True)
```

Comment: Not sure, but could it be the 'know design limitation' discussed [here, in  Blender developer forum](https://developer.blender.org/T37562) ...?